# Creating new table on between date range and join

Tags: sql, t-sql

I've been handed this one which is well outside my comfort level: I have a table with a Start_Date, End_Date and a day of week in which an operation takes place within that start and end date. I'd like to create a table with the ID, the operating date and joined on operating DOW. Below, every monday (Day 1) BETWEEN 11/24/2014 and 12/17/2014 withcreating a new line, continuing through the table. I'm unsure if this requires some kind of cursor or can be done with a CASE WHEN type of schema.

```
TBL_OP_DATA         
ID  START_DATE  END_DATE    OPERATING_DOW
1   11/24/2014  12/17/2014  1
2   12/20/2014  1/7/2015    4
3   11/24/2014  12/17/2014  1
4   12/20/2014  1/7/2015    3

TBL_DAYS        
PKDate  calendar_day_in_week    
11/24/2014  1   
11/25/2014  2   
11/26/2014  3   
11/27/2014  4   
11/28/2014  5   
11/29/2014  6   
11/30/2014  7
```

Result:

```
TBL_OP_BYDAY        
ID  OPERATING_DATE  OPERATING_DOW
1   11/24/2014  1
1   12/1/2014   1
1   12/8/2014   1
1   12/15/2014  1
2   12/25/2014  4
2   1/1/2015    4
```

3   …   …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple JOIN condition, no cursor required:

```
SELECT 
    od.ID,
    d.PKDate AS OPERATING_DATE,
    od.OPERATING_DOW
FROM 
    TBL_DAYS d
     INNER JOIN 
    TBL_OP_DATA od ON
        d.PKDate >= od.START_DATE AND
        d.PKDate <= od.END_DATE AND
        d.CALENDAR_DAY_IN_WEEK = od.OPERATING_DOW
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the easiest way to do it. Assuming that TBL_Days is populated:

```
insert into TBL_OP_BYDAY (Id, operating_date, operating_dow)
select od.Id, d.PKDate, od.operating_dow
from tbl_op_date od
inner join tbl_days d on d.PKDate >= od.start_date 
                     and d.PKDate < od.end_date
                     and d.calendar_day_in_week = od.operating_dow
```

...should do what you want.